# add .properties file in wicket

Tags: wicket

I am using wickets 1.5.I have registration page where fileds has to be validate for only numbers(like phone no) . i have a validation class as below

```
public class Validator implements IValidator<String> {
        Pattern pattern;
        public Validator() {
        pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
        }

        public void validate(IValidatable<String> validatable) {
        final String field = validatable.getValue();

        if (pattern.matcher(field).matches() == false) {

            error(validatable, "phoneno" );
        }

        }

    private void error(IValidatable<String> validatable, String errorKey) {
    ValidationError error = new ValidationError();
    error.addMessageKey(getClass().getSimpleName() + "." + errorKey);
    validatable.error(error);
    }

}
```

I have my Registration.properites file in the same package the Registation.html and .java files are there. 
My **Registration.properites** is

**Registration.phoneno= Please enter numbers only**

I am calling this in my wicket class
**phoneno.add(new Validator());**

I am getting below error

**Could not locate error message for component: TextField@sendform:phoneno and error: [ValidationError message=[null], keys=[Validator.phoneno], variables=[null]]. Tried keys: phoneno.Validator.phoneno, Validator.phoneno.**

What i am doing wrong ?
I have done this as per below link
http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/create-custom-validator-in-wicket/

Answer (score 2):

I think you aren't specifying the property key correctly. The `getClass().getSimpleName()` method is returning "Validator", when your key starts with 'Registration'. Just try this:

```
error.addMessageKey("Registration.phoneno");
```